# Ordered call stacks - with Instruments Time Profiler?

Tags: objective-c, ios, instruments, callstack

I am trying to fix a randomly occurring crash in a iOS app (EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xe104019e). The application performs many operations at the same time - loading data with NSURLConnection, redrawing a complex layout with many nested UIViews, drawing UIImages, caching downloaded files on the local disk, finding out files availability in local cache etc. etc. These operations are distributed into a number of threads and when the crash takes place I am totally confused what exact steps preceded it.

I would like to use a method to track the call stacks in the order of occurrence distributed into threads and see what objects methods were called during last 1-5ms before the crash, then I could isolate the bug that produces the crash.

At first sight the Time Profiler in Instruments offers this kind of tracking ability with many details but sampled call stacks seem to be presented in a random order - or maybe I get it wrong...

Is there a method that would tell me what exactly happens in the order of execution with ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Run with zombies enabled, and removed all compiler and static analyzer warnings.

2) It is likely a threading issue, where you are not protecting your shared data appropriately.

Instruments is quite powerful regarding thread sorting/filtering, but there is no exact template for what you are trying to accomplish.

If you can reduce the problem to a small collection of object types, then you can follow execution based on the reference counts if you add the allocations instrument and enable reference count recording.

Comment: thanks - indeed I suspect a threading issue. I forgot to add I work with iOS5.0 and automatic reference counting (ARC). Unfortunately zombies did not help. I tried using them before...

Comment: @Greg ARC still uses reference counting for every instance. The compiler just adds calls to inc/dec retain counts as needed so... I would assume my proposal would work, even for programs compiled using ARC (although it is possible for ARC to coalesce ref count cycling in some cases). Is that not the case?